# Download deployed Apache Tomcat .war file

Tags: tomcat, deployment, springframework

I am a Apache Tomcat newbie and about to deploy an upgraded version of a Spring MVC application (compiled to a `.war` file) on an Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 server, using Tomcat Web Application Manager.

Because I am not 100% certain that the application will work properly in a production environment, I want to be able to roll back to the currently deployed `.war` file. Since I don't have this file locally but it obviously is on the server, I would like to download it from Tomcat Web Application Manager before I overwrite it.

Is this possible or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have access to the server filesystem I don't think you'll be able to access the existing web application.

If you do have access to the filesystem you should be able to find the deployed webapp in the tomcat web-apps directory, from which you can just copy out the file.

Comment: On my machine I located the `war` files in the folder `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`.